Найти матрицу перехода от базиса к базису

Получается матрица
(-5 2
-2 1)
(векторы записаны по столбцам)
а в калькуляторе выдает обратную к ней. Решал по формуле B = AT, где B - второй базис, A - первый. T нашел решив матричное уравнение. Проверка себя через решение линейных уравнений дала результат такой же как у меня.
Я не прав или калькулятор ?

У меня получилось {{1/2, 1/2}, {3, 0}}. Однако для сайта программистов этот вопрос не слишком подходит.
